# TeX no longer rendered?

Tags: support

What happened? I came back to the site, and TeX is no longer being rendered. Is anybody else having this problem? I didn't make any updates to my browser or other changes that might explain the problem at my end.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same question...

Comment: asked earlier on the network meta too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125478/164022

Comment: It would be interesting to monitor math.SE traffic and know how many answers get posted during the LaTeX down period. I hypothize a reduction in site activity.

Comment: Some very relevant Twitter message: http://twitter.com/#!/MathJax/status/179544978501017602

Comment: mathjax-users google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mathjax-users

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Up again for me!!!

Comment: Seems to be back now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of 14:20 UTC, [MathJax.org is down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mathjax.org), hence all MathJax requests fail.

---

**Edit** From Pierre-Yves' comment: there was an issue with DNS propagation (IP address for the server changed but the DNS didn't update fast enough). The hole is gradually healing itself. As of 16:15 UTC people have reported being about to connect to the mathjax.org domain (though [it](http://www.mathjax.org/) is still not connecting where I am physically).

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. May be I am old-fashioned, but I feel like saying something about reliance to third party SW. On second thought, I'd better not :-)

Comment: So we can't use mathJax except when a certain site other than this one is working?

Comment: Devs have added a means of altering the source for this now, to allow for some sort of fallback when the CDN fails.

Comment: @Michael: it is a bit more complicated then that. Most sites nowadays with high traffic volume uses a [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). This is supposed to improve redundancy, increase available bandwidth, and decrease latency (in other words, much better browsing experience for the user). MathJax uses [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) for this, and has generally functioned quite well. For something using a CDN to fall completely off the grid is quite unlikely. You usually need a very large number of servers to die...

Comment: ...at the same time for hardware problems to be the culprit. So it is not as simple as "certain other site" is not working. Try reading the [MathJax documentation](http://sites.google.com/site/mathjaxproject/design-documents/cdn-hosting-plan/managing-cloudfront-distributions) and have fun guessing what is causing this CDN problem.

Comment: Is the thing your calling "quite unlikely" the same thing that quite likely happened today?

Comment: @Michael: yes. In fact, as the discussion at the mailing list that Pierre-Yves linked to showed, the issue is _not_ with the CDN, but with an DNS update. It is possible that [best practices](http://www.dnswatch.info/articles/dns-update) were not followed, but not knowing more details I can only speculate.